# Excel VBA script assistance

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a VBA script to compare fields in excel. Excel freezes the second I click the button. It never displays any error messages. Every time I try to run it I have to use control alt delete to close excel.
one of my variables is commented out because after I get this to work I plan on copying the data to a different sheet instead of changing the font. just an FYI

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim rng1, rng2, cell1, cell2 As Range
Set rng1 = Worksheets("Main").Range("B:B")
Set rng2 = Worksheets("CSV Transfer").Range("D:D")
'Set rng3 = Worksheets("Data").Range("A:A")

For Each cell1 In rng1
For Each cell2 In rng2

If IsEmpty(cell2.Value) Then Exit For
If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then

 cell1.Font.Bold = True
 cell1.Font.ColorIndex = 2
 cell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 cell1.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
 cell2.Font.Bold = True
 cell2.Font.ColorIndex = 2
 cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 cell2.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid

End If

Next cell2
Next cell1


End Sub
```

Edit: Entire post has been changed to reflect my actual issue.

Comment: You'll need to make an effort to do this on your own. We generally don't write code for you, but rather help you address specific problems you're running into. To get started, you'll want to take a look at the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx). If you get stuck, edit your question to include what code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro isn't freezing, you just aren't giving it enough time to complete - which is a lonnnngggg time.  Excel has a row limit of 1,048,576 rows, and you are comparing every single cell in each row to every single cell in the other row. That's a total of 1,099,511,627,776 cell comparisons. Assuming you can do 100,000 comparisons per second (which is probably a stretch even *without* the formatting), this will eventually complete in just over 127 days.

I'd suggest doing a couple of things. First, when you assign a range to a column like this...

```
Set rng1 = Worksheets("Main").Range("B:B")
```

...you get every *possible* cell - not just the used ones. Find the last non-empty cell in each column, and set your ranges based on that:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ColumnB As Range
With Worksheets("Main")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set ColumnB = .Range("B1:B" + LastRow)
End With
```

This might get your run times onto the order of minutes or seconds instead of days unless you have a huge data set.  To improve them further, stop requesting individual values from the worksheet one at a time and pull them into arrays:

```
Dim BValues As Variant
BValues = ColumnB.Value
```

Then, just loop through and compare values in memory.  It might look something more like this (I pulled the formatting out into a Sub):

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long, MainSheet As Worksheet, CsvSheet As Worksheet

    Set MainSheet = Worksheets("Main")
    Set CsvSheet = Worksheets("CSV Transfer")

    Dim MainValues As Variant
    With MainSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        MainValues = .Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Value
    End With

    Dim CsvValues As Variant
    With CsvSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        CsvValues = .Range("D1:D" & LastRow).Value
    End With

    Dim MainRow As Long, CsvRow As Long
    For MainRow = LBound(MainValues) To UBound(MainValues)
        For CsvRow = LBound(CsvValues) To UBound(CsvValues)
            If MainValues(MainRow) = CsvValues(CsvRow) Then
                FormatCell MainSheet, MainRow, 2
                FormatCell CsvValues, CsvRow, 4
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub FormatCell(sheet As Worksheet, formatRow As Long, formatCol As Long)
    With sheet.Cells(formatRow, formatCol)
        With .Font
            .Bold = True
            .ColorIndex = 2
        End With
        With .Interior
            .ColorIndex = 3
            .Pattern = xlSolid
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I'd also turn off ScreenUpdates at very least if your performance is still too low.

Comment: Great job leaving a thorough and helpful answer!